# how to create Custom Validation Rule for during Update a record in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have added a rule to check the previous password on update user record, but the rule also applies to creating a record, I have added 'update' but still, it's not working.

```
$validator
->scalar('password')
->maxLength('password', 25)
->notEmpty('password', 'Password is required', 'create')
->allowEmpty('password', 'update')
->add('password', 'validFormat', [
        'rule' => ['custom', '/^(?=.*[!@$])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,16}$/i'], 
        'message' => __('Minimum 6 character & alphanumeric with one symbol(!@$) is Required.'), 
        'allowEmpty' => true
])
->add('password', 'custom', [
    'rule' => function($value, $context){
        $user = $this->get($context['data']['id']);

        if ($user) {
            if (!(new DefaultPasswordHasher)->check($value, $user->password)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }, 
    'message' => 'You cannot use your previous password',
    'allowEmpty' => true
], 'update');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `updated` does not do anything as it is not something that CakePHP supports there.

If you read [Custom Validation Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#using-custom-validation-rules) you will see that you can use $context['newRecord'] to determine if this is an update or create.

So, the first line in your validation function could be something like

```
if ($context['newRecord']){
    return true; //new passwords are always valid!
}
```

Alternative way would be to check the $user variable and add an else branch

```
if($user){
    //you already have code here
}else{
    //add this else to return TRUE because for new user, new password is OK
    return true;
}
```